# Why is the "render engine" selection menu missing?

Tags: interface, versions

The dropdown menu to select the render engine (e.g. "Cycles", "Blender Internal", "Blender Game") isn't showing up:

[image: render engine dropdown missing]

I compiled Blender myself (SVN r56975), and although I've enabled `WITH_CYCLES` with CMake at compile time, the Cycles addon warns about missing script files. But the "Blender Game" option should still be there.

Comment: you could try running "blender -b -E help" in the command line to list available render engines.. maybe blender game wasn't enabled?

Comment: Only `BLENDER_RENDER` but I configured CMake with `WITH_GAMEENGINE` and `WITH_CYCLES`. I don't know why they're not there. Also, why would this happen? They should both be working.

Comment: I don't know, though this bug report looks related: http://projects.blender.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=498&aid=31109&group_id=9

Comment: I've never had this problem on this computer (or on any computer I've used Blender on), which is strange. I just did `svn up` and rebuilt it.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to build from source? would using http://builder.blender.org/download/ work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, I change the code, so no.

Comment: Building blender is not topic for the site

Comment: Agreed, but I think that, with a more generic title, this could serve as a good way to explain **(once)** what to do, much like you suggest in http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181/answering-vague-support-questions-once

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short version:

1. check first a build from [builder.blender.org](http://builder.blender.org)
2. then

   - verify source modifications
   - verify build settings
3. fix your modifications or build settings.

When you see weird behavior in own builds for which you also have changed source **always** check a build from [builder.blender.org](http://builder.blender.org) . If the unexpected behavior doesn't show up with such a nightly test-build, then you should review your modifications and build settings as they are apparently the cause for the behavior.

For building settings and troubleshooting of builds, refer to [the build instructions](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev%3aDoc/Building_Blender) for your own platform and build system. There are trouble shoot sections for each way.

If on the other hand the unexpected behavior is replicable with such a build, then you likely have found a bug, at which point you should be reporting that to [projects.blender.org](http://projects.blender.org)